# How to prevent data repeat in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem on displaying data of `$variant_choice`, which it will be called repeat as long as i select a data from same id.

This is my code how to call `$variant_choice`:

```
if(($a["choice"])!== NULL) {
   foreach($a["choice"] as $val){
       $variant_menu_choice[] = $this->Restaurants_m->m_get_menu_choice2_by_id($val);
   }

}
foreach($variant_menu_choice as $value){
    $choice[] = $value["variant_name"];
}

$variant_choice = implode("<br/>",$choice);
```

Example :

If  i click a data `golden_salmon` which it will contain `$variant_choice`.
First if i choose `spicy` in `golden salmon`, it will nothing problem, but if for the secondly i choose another `$variant_choice` as `salty`, it will be return become `spicy` and `salty`

Comment: you are sending multiple choices. $a["choice"]

Comment: how to prevent it? because $a["choice"] is coming from my session, it will added as long as menu was added, than it will be become multiple @RakeshKumar

Comment: don't use it from session, use only things which are selected as choice.